# How can we convert a character string such as "2007-11-31 13:15:54" to a as.Date format in R?

Tags: r

I have a data table with a character string read in using the `fread` option in the `data.table` package. As such, it converts "2007-11-31 13:15:54" into a character string. The string "2007-11-31 13:15:54" represents "%Y-%m-%d %hh-%mm-%ss" in date notation.

I am trying to convert this type of character string into a `Date` format. I am using the `as.Date` function in R.

My first try is to do:

```
char.string <- "2007-11-31 13:15:54"
convert <- as.Date(char.string, "%Y-%m-%d %hh-%mm-%ss")
```

However, all I get when I return `convert` is `NA`.

Is there some way to convert this type of character string? Thanks!

Comment: The `Date` class doesn't include times. See `?DateTimeClasses`, and your format is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't help that November doesn't have 31 days. Something like `strptime("2007-11-30 13:15:54", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the answer online. Instead of as.Date, use ymd_hms() under the package lubridate.